# PyQt: Combobox not displaying

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, qcombobox, qcheckbox

I'm trying to write a python script using PyQt. I want to grab from a sqlite db some info and then display it in checkboxes inside a scroll-area in case the list gets too big:

```
def addCheckBox(self):
    cbCurrentTxt = str(self.comboBox.currentText())
    db = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
    x = 10
    for checkBoxPop in db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE week='"+cbCurrentTxt+"';"):
        print checkBoxPop
        self.checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.scrollArea)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, x, 95, 25))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainwiNdow", str(checkBoxPop[1]), None))

        self.checkBox_2 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.scrollArea)        
        self.checkBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, x, 95, 25))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("MainwiNdow", str(checkBoxPop[3]), None))         
        for i in checkBoxPop[1]:
            print "coord" + str(x)
            x += 4
```

I'm using a combobox to get the week:

```
def populateWeekCB(self):
    db = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    self.comboBox.clear()
    for cbItemsDB in db.execute("select * from week"):
        print cbItemsDB
        self.comboBox.addItem(cbItemsDB[0])
    self.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.addCheckBox)
```

After the week gets selected, I want to display the checkboxes, but they aren't showing.